# creating a module with pythonqt

Tags: python, qt

Is there any pythonqt documentation for `createModuleFromFile`?  I've gotten pythonqt set up, but I'm not sure if I'm creating the module correctly to be seen in another context.  In the following code, I try to create a new module from a file, which contains a class that I want to inherit from in another file.

Reading the docs, it implies `createModuleFromFile` creates another context, but I can't run code from it and I'll need to import more than one module anyway.  Is anything else necessary to accomplish this?  Right now it errors when trying to execute the second script with an ImportError saying that module doesn't exist.  I've also tried just evaluating both scripts back to back without the import line, but then `MeshImporter` isn't defined in the second script.

```
PythonQt::init(PythonQt::RedirectStdOut);
PythonQtObjectPtr context = PythonQt::self()->getMainModule();

QObject::connect(PythonQt::self(), SIGNAL(pythonStdOut(QString)), this, SLOT(pythonStdOut(QString)));
QObject::connect(PythonQt::self(), SIGNAL(pythonStdErr(QString)), this, SLOT(pythonStdOut(QString)));

PythonQt::self()->createModuleFromFile("meshImporter", ":/plugins/meshImporter.py");
context.evalFile(":/plugins/objImporter.py");
```

Example module:

```
class MeshImporter:
    def extension(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()
    def importMesh(self, fileName):
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

Example script that tries to import module:

```
from meshImporter import MeshImporter # fails here

class ObjImporter(MeshImporter):
    def extension(self): return '.obj'
    def importMesh(self, fileName):
        print('Importing mesh: %s' % fileName)
```